# Multi div id hide/show Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get a div to show and hide based on a dropdown.

I have 3 hidden divs but only 2 show. The issue is I have to have multiple ID's for some divs.
the two display as handset are fine but the id="Handset Tablet" won't show. Does my jquery need to see if it just contains the id as I guess it is just looking for "Handset" not two.

Here is my code. I need to have all 3 divs with Handset show and Tablet only show the shared one somehow.
http://jsfiddle.net/jonasj/k2sxdh5s/

```
   <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <select name="product_type" id="product_type" class="form-control check_record">
                <option selected value="0" >-Select Product Type-</option>
                <option value="Handset">Handset</option>
                <option value="Tablet" >Tablet</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>




        <div id="Handset" class="hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Spec</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control" name="spec">
                <option selected value="" disbaled>- Device Spec -</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Handset" class="hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Capacity</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control" name="device_capacity">
                <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Capacity -</option>
                <option value="2GB">2GB</option>
                <option value="4GB">4GB</option>
                <option value="8GB">8GB</option>
                <option value="16GB">16GB</option>
                <option value="32GB">32GB</option>
                <option value="64GB">64GB</option>
                <option value="128GB">128GB</option>
                <option value="256GB">256GB</option>
                <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Handset Tablet" class="hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sim Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control" name="device_sim">
                <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Sim Status -</option>
                <option value="Sim Free">Sim Free</option>
                <option value="Network Locked">Network Locked</option>
                <option value="Network Unlocked">Network Unlocked</option>
                <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>    




<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hide_listing').hide();
  $('').show();
  $('#product_type').change(function () {
    $('.hide_listing').hide();
    $('div#'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique. When you select an ID, it will just return the first one. Use a class if you need multiple instances.

Comment: An ID may not contain spaces : http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.core
Your HTML is invalid

Comment: What is `$('').show()` supposed to do? `$('')` doesn't select anything.

Comment: It looks like you want to use "Handset" as a class, rather than an id, so that you can apply it to several elements.

Comment: ID's are unique . Use a class,name or HTML5's data-* attributes like data-id

Comment: id's should be unique, u must use a class to do this. try this. http://jsfiddle.net/k2sxdh5s/5/

Answer (score 1):

Since IDs are unique, you can use classes to achieve what you want:

```
     <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="product_type" id="product_type" class="form-control check_record">
            <option selected value="0" >-Select Product Type-</option>
            <option value="Handset">Handset</option>
            <option value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>




    <div class="Handset hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Spec</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="spec">
            <option selected value="" disbaled>- Device Spec -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Handset hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Capacity</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="device_capacity">
            <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Capacity -</option>
            <option value="2GB">2GB</option>
            <option value="4GB">4GB</option>
            <option value="8GB">8GB</option>
            <option value="16GB">16GB</option>
            <option value="32GB">32GB</option>
            <option value="64GB">64GB</option>
            <option value="128GB">128GB</option>
            <option value="256GB">256GB</option>
            <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Handset Tablet hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sim Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="device_sim">
            <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Sim Status -</option>
            <option value="Sim Free">Sim Free</option>
            <option value="Network Locked">Network Locked</option>
            <option value="Network Unlocked">Network Unlocked</option>
            <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And change your function to include the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hide_listing').hide();
  $('#product_type').change(function () {
  $('.hide_listing').hide();
  $('div.'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

Though you may want to just go with classes all together, as to avoid confusion in the future.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/k2sxdh5s/7/

Comment: This is a good answer except you left a lot of junk in. http://jsfiddle.net/k2sxdh5s/4/ is what I was working on, you don't need $('').show(); or $('div#'+$(this).val()).show();

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about cleaning it up, just got it working! Edited to reflect the clean snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Put this as HTML

```
    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="product_type" id="product_type" class="form-control check_record">
            <option selected value="0" >-Select Product Type-</option>
            <option value="Handset">Handset</option>
            <option value="Tablet" >Tablet</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>




    <div class="Handset hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Spec</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="spec">
            <option selected value="" disbaled>- Device Spec -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Handset hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Capacity</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="device_capacity">
            <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Capacity -</option>
            <option value="2GB">2GB</option>
            <option value="4GB">4GB</option>
            <option value="8GB">8GB</option>
            <option value="16GB">16GB</option>
            <option value="32GB">32GB</option>
            <option value="64GB">64GB</option>
            <option value="128GB">128GB</option>
            <option value="256GB">256GB</option>
            <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Handset Tablet hide_listing form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sim Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" name="device_sim">
            <option selected disabled value="">- Select Device Sim Status -</option>
            <option value="Sim Free">Sim Free</option>
            <option value="Network Locked">Network Locked</option>
            <option value="Network Unlocked">Network Unlocked</option>
            <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and put this as jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.hide_listing').hide();
  $('#product_type').change(function () {
    $('.hide_listing').hide();
    var show_div = $(this).val();
      if(show_div == "Handset") {
          $(".Handset").show();
      } else if (show_div == "Tablet") {
          $(".Tablet").show();
      }
  })
});
```

This will make it work...surely